# Loop inside a loop, where is the mutual inductance greatest?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance, magnetics, mutual-inductance

I had a question while working a problem as to where the mutual inductance of a circular loop inside a rectangular loop is greatest.

Is it at the center, because the magnetic field of all four wire segments converge on it,or is it at an edge or corner, making it closer to the magnetic fields?

Here is a picture of the loops in question:

[image]

Comment: Does this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcbuUDUWx8Y partially answer your question ?